# Java - How to only accept positive numbers

Tags: java, input, numbers, decimal

I write a program where I need to take user input (prices) and giving the sum of all prices as output. Naturally prices can't be negative, so my question is: How does the program accept positive numbers only?

Comment: You would use a loop and keep asking user to input correct value and exit loop once they do so.

Comment: How can i do that? I would need to make a certain value true in the condition once it's positive (so for what i can think of). But how do I keep asking to re-enter a value?

Comment: `while (a certain value < 0) {Ask user again and then update the value}`

Comment: Thank you Goion. I've solved my issue.

Comment: For future reference you will want to make a post with code you've already written/tried, and ask for advice/corrections. You will get downvoted a lot if you post a question asking for code when you haven't shown us your efforts yet.

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll keep that in mind. I've already written some code about it. but i hoped that there would be a function instead of a method. Anyways my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a price: ");
        double number = input.nextDouble();
        while (number < 0 ) {
            System.out.print("Sorry, but your price must be a positive decimal. Enter a price:  ");
            number = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("Your price is " + number);
    }
}
```

Use a while loop to keep re-checking if the entered price meets your standards.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that while loop

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it worked as aspected.